# Python callback argument issue

Tags: python-2.7, ros

I'm new to python. I have the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

#defines a callback
def callback(msg):
    rospy.init_node('obstacle_avoidance')
    pub = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
    rate = rospy.Rate(1)

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        print('==================================')

        print('CHECKING .....')
        print msg.ranges


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        callback()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

With the following response:

> TypeError: callback() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

I understand what the error is saying but the `msg` variable is not one I defined so I'm not sure what to pass.

Comment: You don't call callbacks directly.  Have you read the http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Tutorials?

Comment: @MarkTolonen: You mean like the publisher in http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber?
To me, it looks like it's calling a callback directly.

Comment: Not in section 2.1.  Subscriber registers the callback.  Which are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be combining 2 tutorials in a way that doesn't work. You call `callback()` but don't provide an argument which makes it crash because `callback()` expects an argument.

You then use `msg.ranges` in your function. (which is a Laser message idea).

You should probably do something like this

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

#defines a callback
def callback(msg):
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        print('==================================')
        print('CHECKING .....')
        print msg.ranges


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        rospy.init_node('obstacle_avoidance')
        pub = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
        rospy.Subscriber('/base_scan', LaserScan, callback)
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```